# Codeigniter: Passing helper functions to the CI error_404.php file

Tags: codeigniter, error-handling

I'm in the process of customizing the CI **error_404.php** file located in `application/errors/error_404.php` but somehow it doesn't recognize the helper function `base_url()`. Is it because it's an error and not a view?

How can I pass helper functions when `url` is already autoloaded in config.php?

**Edit:** I'm obviously just trying to customize my 404 page. Am I looking at this the wrong way??

Comment: See http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/172619/#820845

Comment: If you are running CI2 you could just set the 404_override route to an error controller. This won't effect the show_404() 404 page though http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I would do:
error_404.php

```
$CI =& get_instance();
if( ! isset($CI))
{
    $CI = new CI_Controller();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the 404 error can be shown long before the autoloaded items are called.

Here's what I would do:

```
<?php
if(!function_exists('base_url'))
{
    include BASEPATH.'helpers/url_helper.php';
}
?>

// 404 error content here...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$this->config->config['base_url'];
```

if you want do a

```
print_r($this);
```

Comment: I also tried `print_r($this)`, but the result on the errors/error_404.php page was just an exception:


CI_Exceptions Object
(
    [action] => 
    [severity] => 
    [message] => 
    [filename] => 
    [line] => 
    [ob_level] => 0
    [levels] => Array
        (
            [1] => Error
            ...
            [2048] => Runtime Notice
        )

)

Answer (score 0):

Just define BASE_URL as constants in constants.php and require that constants.php in error404.php